# How to correctly restore a backup to corrupted btrfs?

Tags: backup, btrfs

I have btrfs with some amount of corruption that in logs looks like that:

```
BTRFS warning (device dm-0): csum failed root 261 ino 638264 off 6221824 csum 0x3315c12e expected csum 0xc1eecea6 mirror 1
BTRFS error (device dm-0): bdev /dev/mapper/cryptroot errs: wr 16, rd 1, flush 0, corrupt 16112, gen 0
```

I also have an externally stored snapshot with no corruption.
What should I use to restore? I consider btrfs send/receive or rsync, but I'm not sure if they can handle file corruption and not mess up any meta. I can probably reformat, rewrite and reencrypt the whole disk, but that would take forever.

`btrfs check` reports only checksum errors. `btrfs check --repair` didn't help.

UPD:

So I restored with `rsync -aiAXHSc --cc=xxh3 --inplace --del`. Now everything is working. Everything that was corrupt is fine now. But.

`btrfs scrub` still reports 19000 blocks with the wrong csum. Checked some problematic inodes with `btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve`. Most of them returned `ERROR: logical ino ioctl: No such file or directory`. Files that were returned by some of them were perfectly fine.
Files that are mentioned in logs with csum errors are either fine or don't exist.
`btrfs check` as before returns only csum errors.

I have no idea what's going on.